# '<EOF>' in subquery source in Hive query

Tags: sql, hive

I am running a query on Hive similar to:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT a
      FROM b
      WHERE
      sex = 'M'
      AND   degree = 'Bs'
      AND   age = 15
      AND   name LIKE 'L%'
      );
```

the error is:

```
cannot recognize input near '<EOF>' '<EOF>' '<EOF>' in subquery source
```

Comment: Did you try remove `AND` condition to see which one give you error?

Comment: "Similar to" does not help because it seems like a syntax issue

Comment: Dudu Markovitz: by simiar, I meant I Just changed tables name to a and b and column names to age, ..., otherwise it is exactly the same.

Comment: ... and by that you have masked possible issue of reserved words

Comment: Missing alias name for subquery.

Comment: FWIW, I wish Hive gave a better error for this issue

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Adding a table alias for your subquery is necessary for Hive. Below I use 't1' as the alias:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT a
  FROM b
  WHERE
  sex = 'M'
  AND   degree = 'Bs'
  AND   age = 15
  AND   name LIKE 'L%'
  ) t1 ;
```

Comment: this is great .. worked for me .. but can you please explain what difference it made exactly ?

Answer (score 6):

All the down-votes are unjustified. Hive often does not produce correct error and throws lazy "EOF" at you. In this case you just need to specify table alias for your sub-query. `SELECT * FROM (.....) tbl_alias`

Comment: I guess some Hive fan is just down-voting anything that mentions hive bugs